# Magnifying bubble for water assets similar to a data frame inset

Tags: arcgis-water-utilities

I work with the Water Dept for a municipality and enter water assets such as valves, pipes, manholes, etc., into ArcGIS Desktop. At times a physical map of the location of these assets is needed for the street crews (not a refined, pretty map but a basic, simple map). Valves, at pipe intersections, are constructed close to each other, and when a map is printed at the scale used to show the entire area that needs attention, the valve symbols appear as one blob of valves, or just as one valve, instead of many.

This would be similar to a data frame inset, but I need something that our street crews can create on their own, and they are not very ArcGIS literate.

Can I create a callout bubble similar in appearance to labeling call-out bubbles but shows targeted assets (instead of labelling) at a close-up view? This would show both a scaled-out area and the close-up of a specific intersection. And I would need a way to make this available when printing sections of a map display.

This is a general idea of what I’m looking for (created in Powerpoint)
[image]

Comment: This sounds like an idea you should post on the ESRI ideas website? But you confuse matters, you say "...our street crews can create on their own.." which is suggesting you are asking about some sort of mobile mapping application to be used in the field? Then you say ".. to make this available when printing .." which suggests _you_ are creating map Layouts which is something completely different?

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified that the street crews print, not create, the maps on their own. If we could keep this digital with them this wouldn't be an issue.

And thanks for the advice on posting this on Esri Ideas webpage. I will do just that.

Comment: I would suggest you explore ArcGIS Collector if you have not. You create a map on ArcGIS Online and they could simply look at that and zoom into any part of the map, using a tablet or smart phone and even update live in the field if you wished. Paper is dead long live the mobile App!